# Mockito : how to mock constructor parameter without calling its method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class like this:

```
class A extends Parent {

  B b;
  public A(B b) {
    super(b);
    this.b = b;
  }

  public void method() {
     b.something()
  }
}
```

And its super class is :

```
class Parent {

private Factory factory;

public Parent(B b) {
  factory.someMethod(b)
}
```

My goal is to inject mock B into A, then mock the `method` inside A.

The problem is that, if I inject B into A, when A calls its constructor, it will fail because the `factory` is not injected. And I have no right to modify the existing code.

What is the good way to do this ?

Comment: how is the factory being set ?

Comment: You could mock the factory ?

Answer (score 1):

Mockito gives u the leverage to suppress the constructor call

You can try suppressing constructor call for B

using

```
suppress(constructor(B.class));
```

remember to add B in prepare for test annotation
i.e

```
@PrepareForTest({B.class})
```

do this inside the Class writing test for A class. It will Suppress the B constructor call.

Comment: I didn't know we can do this... but where should I put suppress(constructor(B.class));  ? I need to instantiate the mock of a using a = new A(b), if I put afterwards it'll be too late, if I put before it there is no b yet

Answer (score 0):

The factory could be injected via the constructor, too. Then you can mock it.

```
class Parent {

  private Factory factory;

  public Parent(
    Factory factory,
    B b
  ) {
    factory.someMethod(b)
  }
```

But IMO generally a constructor should not execute anything but just assign parameters to fields. This makes it much easier to test code.

Comment: No the Parent class does not have a constructor where I can pass inside the factory mock... and I cannot create one because it's inside one library